# Why Does Clang See a Type Conflict?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, clang, header-files

RESOLVED!

Maybe I'm losing my edge, but to me I don't see why Clang is giving me the following error when I compile my linked list file (llist).

```
error: conflicting types for 'remove'

int remove(struct node *llist, int val);

note: previous declaration is here
extern int remove(const char *__filename) __THROW;
```

My .h file:

```
struct node{
  int val;
  struct node *left, *right;
};

struct node* get(struct node *llist, int i);
int remove(struct node *llist, int val);
struct node* search(int val, struct node *llist);
void deleteList(struct node *llist);
void add(struct node *llist, struct node *toAdd);
```

My .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "llist.h"



int remove(struct node *llist, int val){
  struct node *cur = llist->right;
  while(cur != llist){
    if(cur->val != val)
      cur = cur->right;
    else{
      cur->left->right = cur->right;
      cur->right->left = cur->left;
      free(cur);
      return 1;
    } 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `remove` function to delete a file already exists in `<stdio.h>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a standard function named `remove` in `stdio.h` that has a signature of:

```
int remove(const char *filename);
```

Rename your function.

---

Note: as @R.. points out, the name `remove` is reserved even if `stdio.h` is not included.

Comment: Note that even if `stdio.h` is not included, `remove` is reserved as an identifier with external linkage, and thus it's illegal to define your own external function named `remove`.

Comment: Ah thank you! I'm coming from being a C++ data structures and algorithms programmer and need to implement them again in C for my OS class, and I didn't figure there'd be these pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try and compile this reduced test case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct node;
int remove(struct node *llist, int val);
```

If we compile this, we get the following notifications:

```
foo.c:3:5: error: conflicting types for 'remove'
int remove(struct node *llist, int val);
    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:261:6: note: previous declaration is here
int      remove(const char *);
         ^
1 error generated.
```

This tells us pretty clearly that `stdio.h` has already defined a `remove()` function, and you need to rename your function.

If you're interested in what that `remove()` does, you can learn about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove).

Comment: did you compile with GCC or a special flag? Clang -Wall -g ... doesn't give me this same prompt. Thank you though for the warning. It figures C is even more prickly than C++ was...

Comment: I compiled this with `clang foo.c`

Comment: Weird, usually Wall is more helpful... Thank you.